# UILabel adds unnecessary top and bottom padding when growing vertically and breaking lines

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, uilabel

Let's say we have a `UILabel`, that is pinned from all sides to its superview. Number of `Lines` is set to 0 (so we can display multiline strings) and we use `Truncate Tails` strategy for line breaks.

If we have a **single, short line of text**, which does not break lines, the label's inside padding/inset looks fine:

[image: Single line of text]

When using **multiline text**, that will force the label to start breaking lines, ellipsis appear at the end of the label, but **artificial padding/inset** is added to top/bottom of the label as well. The label is inflated vertically, even though it is still displaying only 1 line of text:

[image: Multiline text]

Constraints:

[image: Constraints]

Line breaks:

[image: Line breaks]

**What I tried already**

Changed `Content Hugging Priority` to `1000` for both Horizontal and Vertical axis, so the UILabel doesn't grow more than required, but that does not solve the issue.

Switching between different `Line Breaks` strategies (Clip, Character Wrap, Truncate, ...) does not solve the issue either.

I am able to reproduce this behavior in both `Xcode 6` and `Xcode 7 beta`, Interface Builder and while running the app.

Comment: Did you try to call [YourLabel sizeToFit]?

Comment: @Walucas: Yes I tried that, but with no success. This issue presents itself both in Interface Builder and running application.

Comment: Did you tried to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` in code? You can set it to `self.frame.size.width - 2*8` which fits your margins.

Comment: @CandostDagdeviren thanks, but no luck either

Comment: Did you changed the frame of your view? Because your bottom space constraint should be grater than 20 and it prevents your UILabel's getting bigger in vertical.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the only way to fix the unintentional padding is to set `Lines` to a constant (eg. 3). The `UILabel` will still grow dynamically and will refrain from adding any padding.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the 'explicit' checkbox in Interface builder for the Desired width of the label solved this for me.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem when see it in interface builder. But if i just run it the final result in simulator works without any padding.
The key is you have to set the `backgroundColor` property of the label.